# Is it possible to left align the X-axis label in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I can't find it! :-)

I simply what the x-axis label "cyl" to become left-aligned. Surely this is possible.

Example (mpg in ggplot package):

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy))
g + geom_boxplot(varwidth=T, fill="plum") + 
  labs(title="Box plot", x="cyl",y="hwy")
```

[image]

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the alignment of the axis title via `theme` option `axis.title.x`, `axis.title.y` or `axis.title`.

To left align the x axis title set `hjust = 0` in `axis.title.x`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T, fill = "plum") +
  labs(title = "Box plot", x = "cyl", y = "hwy") 

p +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]

To move the y axis title to the bottom aka to left align the y axis title set `hjust = 0` in `axis.title.y`:

```r
p +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]

And both could be achieved at once using `axis.title`:

```r
p +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(hjust = 0)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot about axis.title.x. Similar question: how can I move the axis.title.y to the bottom of the axis.

Comment: `axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0)` or do both at once using `axis.title = element_text(hjust = 0)`